# How can I copy-and-paste Data into MySQL Workbench table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, ssms

I've used `MySQL Workbench` and `MS SQL Server Management Studio` off & on over the years.  The one thing I enjoy with `SSMS` is the ability to copy information from an Excel document and paste it into the results pane of `SSMS`.  Is there a similar means of importing information into tables for `MySQL Workbench`?  This method is quick and easy.  Right now the way I do it for MySQL is I export from excel to CSV file, then import to MySQL from CSV file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to insert an entire Excel table into a result set in MySQL Workbench using only the clipboard. For this task your approach via a CSV file is the best one. There's an option to copy/paste entire rows, though, which might be of help for small changes.

Answer (score 2):

### Third Party Tool with CSV

If you are willing to use a third party tool, you can paste from an Excel worksheet select-copy or a CSV open in a text editor into [this tool](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) to generate `INSERT INTO` or `UPDATE` statements.  It can also add the `CREATE TABLE` with appropriately sized `VARCHAR`s as an option (among many other output options).  You copy and paste from the tool directly into a blank SQL page in mySQL Workbench.

### Third Party Tool with Regex

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression tool such as https://regex101.com to generate the SQL code.  For example, a three field csv that's tab separated can be decoded by this regex

```
^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)$
```

and then in the Substitution expression, this

```
INSERT INTO `myschema`.`mytable` SET `first_field`='$1', `second_field`='$2', `third_field`= TRIM('$3'), `outbox_sent_text` = 'Friday, December 04, 2020 12:28 PM', `inbox_received_text` = 'Fri, 4 Dec 2020 15:43:08 +0000' AS `NEW` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;
```

Note this substitution uses the updated `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method that will [replace the deprecated `VALUES` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13325)

Copy the block of `INSERTs` into an empty Workbench SQL window, and run the query.

### Third party not OK? Not a problem, works locally too

If sending this through a web site is not allowable, the same regex substitution can be done with a local script or local text editing tool ([Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), etc.).